# How to create a signature using HMACSHA1 and secret key to connect to Kayako API

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to connect to a third party application API using apache commons HTTP Client. The API I'm trying to connect is http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DEV/REST+API.

The API requires me to pass a API key and a signature along with a salt used to create the signature.

As per the API documentation these are the steps to create the signature

1. Generate a random string to create a salt (in PHP, you would use mt_and() to do this)
2. Generate the signature by hashing the salt using SHA256 with the secret key as the key (in PHP, you would use hash_hmac() to do this)
3. base64 encode the signature (in PHP, you would use base64_encode() to do this)
4. URL encode the output (in PHP, you would use urlencode() to do this)

**UPDATED**

As per the responses I got, I changes some of my code and created a demo account with the Kayako to test the API

I'm using the following class to generate the signature

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64Encoder;

public class GenSign2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException,
            IOException {
        String secretKey = "M2Y2YjkxZDEtYmNlOC1mYmI0LTkxZTgtOTNiY2RiMDhmN2E2YjExNGUwYjktNGJkYy1jZTM0LWQ1MWYtZGIwYWRlZTE0NGNh";
        String salt = "0123456789";

        String generateHmacSHA256Signature = generateHmacSHA256Signature(salt,
                secretKey);
        System.out.println("Signature: " + generateHmacSHA256Signature);

        String urlEncodedSign = URLEncoder.encode(generateHmacSHA256Signature,
                "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("Url encoded value: " + urlEncodedSign);
    }

    public static String generateHmacSHA256Signature(String data, String key)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        byte[] hmacData = null;

        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    "HmacSHA256");
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(secretKey);
            hmacData = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            new Base64Encoder().encode(hmacData, 0, hmacData.length, bout);
            return bout.toString("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the test api is as follows

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class TestApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apikey",
                "f165dc40-ce3f-6864-7d5e-27a7188b2e62"));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("salt", "0123456789"));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signature", "mbrhpXkP0LzNMNDygHAorqMx%2FDGovl%2FauMTOMB6RNMA%3D"));

        HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(
                "http://aruntest.kayako.com/api/index.php?e=/Core/Test");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
        System.out.println(response.getProtocolVersion());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
    }

}
```

The demo site can be accessed using 
URL: http://aruntest.kayako.com/admin/ 
User: admin 
Password: ty386rhjzz

It is throwing an unauthorized access exception when I'm trying to connect.

Comment: In your four steps to create the signature, I don't see any reference to the data that you are trying to sign. Got an URL to the actual API documentation? :)

Comment: I think you've got a problem with your first call to `System.arraycopy()` -- it appears you are copying `0` bytes. Try swapping `salt.length` and `0` in the first call, and see if this improves the situation.

Comment: @sarnold I'm trying to connect to http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DEV/REST+API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kayako has updated their documentation with a new [java sample](http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DEV/Generating+an+API+Signature#GeneratinganAPISignature-JavaExample) which works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try and compare your signature method with this (it works)

```
public static String generateHmacSHA256Signature(String data, String key)   throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] hmacData = null;

    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(secretKey);
        hmacData = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(hmacData);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw new GeneralSecurityException(e);
    }
}
```

The **result** of this call, will then be the **value** of your attribute **Signature**

```
String signature = generateHmacSHA256Signature(salt, key);
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signature", signature));
```

A simple way to generate a salt/nonce

```
String nonce = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

See [Example:](http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DEV/REST+API)

Comment: The `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`. You can use any flavour you want.

Comment: @GregS, is there other valid Base64 classes that's part of the JDK?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: As far as I know you must either write your own or use a third-party implementation. Shame on Sun (now Oracle) for this fact, but you should never use a sun.* class. They might not be there next update, they might not be in the IBM runtime or others, etc. Your code is not considered pure Java if you use them.

Comment: @GregS, true, hence I said earlier, you can use any flavour you want. I just showed how to just create HMAC-SHA256 signature.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I have no doubt that you understand but you have to think of the children! They'll copy&paste without knowing the consequences.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Since JDK 8 there's [java.util.Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) you can use here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the entire `getSaltedKey()` routine is unnecessary. You're just signing the salt (it should have been called a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)) with HMAC and signing with the provided key, it doesn't look like you're supposed to sign the key+salt.